# конвертация символов php

Tags: unicode

есть строка "&#x22email" или "&#x3a10", как определить код символа и верно его конвертировать? в js например "\x22email" будет '"'(\x22), а никак не "Ȯ"(\x22e). Я понимаю, что должен быть символ окончания ";", но он не всегда есть.

Comment: Браузер определяет именно Ȯ. Непонятно, по каким причинам нужно считать, что Ȯ это неправильно

Comment: В js после `\x` идет РОВНО ДВА символа, обозначающие код, поэтому там и определяется `"`. В HTML точной длины кода нет (например, `&#x1f30e;` это символ  — тут целых пять символов определяют код), и следовательно точка с запятой должна быть ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО. Если точки с запятой нет — как догадаться, что это не Ȯ?